# How to add fonts into Asset Studio that's part of Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a very simple app launcher icon in text via Asset Studio.
I'd like to know how could I add my own font in the Source Asset menu located in the the Foreground Layer tab?

I'm doing this for an Udacity course project, I am a complete newbie.

[image]

Comment: Which IDE are you using.

Comment: Android Studio 3.0.1, on Linux Mint. Zoe's answer did it for me though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asset Studio takes the fonts from the system. So the fonts you are seeing are the fonts you have installed. To add another font, just install the font.

On Windows, open the font file and it should give you the option to install (at least it works for `.ttf` files, other formats are different). If you use a different OS, you'll have to look up the font installation instruction

Comment: Thank you, I installed the font I wanted and it's there now. It was simple enough. It didn't cross my mind that they were my system's. 
I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score -3):

you can put your font file with ttf format into your project asset folder \font.

Comment: Doesn't add the file to Asset Studio, it just adds it to the project

Comment: I tried this method before, but I only managed to use it to change a TextView's font, and not to add it to the Asset Studio to create my launcher icon in text. 
However Zoe's answer helped me figure it out.