# How to use desired font in Image Asset in Android Studio?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, text, icon-fonts

I was trying to change the application icon of my project. I figured out i had to use Image Asset to create it. I chose the background image and while i chose the foreground to have text. I couldn't use a custom font in it. Any solutions?

Image link to my problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDPmy.png

Can't upload image as i don't have enough reputation points yet.

I tried to check the xml files created by it after clicking OK.. but couldn't find any font-family attribute there.
Also tried to search how to add custom fonts to source asset but with no success I only found the answers to add them to the project instead of Image Asset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add fonts into Asset Studio that's part of Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972345/how-to-add-fonts-into-asset-studio-thats-part-of-android-studio)

Comment: Thank you so much to bring that to my attention.. i really don't know why couldn't i search for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#text)

> You can use the fonts that are installed on your computer.

So you should first install the font, then you should be able to see it in the selector.

[Install a font on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201749)

[Install a font on Windows10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/how-do-i-install-a-new-font-open-sans-in-windows/ba771264-72ac-4597-b62b-5ca861945f08)

**Edit**: found [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972345/how-to-add-fonts-into-asset-studio-thats-part-of-android-studio) of your question